# GWT TabLayoutPanel -> doesn't show tab content

Tags: java, gwt

If I use the new TabLayoutPanel to create my TabPanel it doesn't show the tab content. Just the tab headers are shown. If I use the same code with `TabPanel` instead of `TabLayoutPanel` it works as expected. I can't figure out what is the problem here:

```
TabLayoutPanel tabs = new TabLayoutPanel(200, Unit.PX);
tabs.add(new Label("tabContent1"), "tab1");
tabs.add(new HTMLPanel("tabContent2"), "tab2");
tabs.add(new HTML("tabContent3"), "tab3");
RootPanel.get().add(tabs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i figured it out. I need to used the `RootLayoutPanel` to add the Layout Panels to the page instead of the `RootPanel`. The code works like this:

```
TabLayoutPanel tabs = new TabLayoutPanel(200, Unit.PX);
tabs.add(new Label("tabContent1"), "tab1");
tabs.add(new HTMLPanel("tabContent2"), "tab2");
tabs.add(new HTML("tabContent3"), "tab3");
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(tabs);
```

Comment: You can use the RootPanel but it is not a suggested way. You need to set a height for tabLayouPanel if you use rootPanel.

Answer (score 1):

As per [TablayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html) docs

*This widget will only work in standards mode, which requires that the HTML page in which it is run have an explicit  declaration*

It seems problem with the DOCTYPE of your `host html page` .

can please  verify that your host HTML page has the doctype for standards mode only? 
Try with changing `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

And if you see docs of [TabPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html)

> This widget will only work in quirks mode. If your application is in Standards Mode, use TabLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: The doctype is in standards mode

Comment: dead link to TableLayoutPanel.